# Looker: Create an explore minus required date fields

Tags: looker

I'm fairly new to looker. There's this explore I'd like to use to build a table. It has all the view files I need joined to it, mainly one view file named insights.view. However, insights.view is currently used with dates and I'd like to create a new explore minus these date dimensions. In the current explore these date dimensions are required filters. How should I go about creating this new explore with only the dimensions I need and w/o the date filters from the insights.view?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear but based on what I understand , perhaps this help https://community.looker.com/lookml-5/hiding-fields-from-a-view-in-different-explores-16503 . Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the date dimensions are the issue, but the fact that the explore that currently exists has required filters on those dimensions.

You could copy/paste the explore definition and not bring in the required filters.

Or it'd be better to extend the Explore and try something like this depending on how they made the filters required:
https://help.looker.com/hc/en-us/articles/4420210624659-When-extending-an-explore-can-I-exclude-an-existing-parameter-like-always-filter-or-conditionally-filter-on-the-new-extended-explore-Community-